# How to check null value or row have all zero value or have multiple value

Tags: excel, vb.net, for-loop, nested-loops

```
Dim copiedContent As String = Request.Form(txtCopied.UniqueID)
            For Each row As String In copiedContent.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(row) <> "0" Then
                    dtResult.Rows.Add()
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    For Each cell As String In row.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
                        dtResult.Rows(dtResult.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell
                        i += 1
                    Next
                End If
            Next
```

Hi all, based on code above how can i reject if the inserting value is all zero value? [allzerovalue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwclJ.png) and how to let in inserting value that have zero [anyvaluewithzero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5UOa.png).
Please help...Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the "Key" you mention in this context?  Could you please expand that?  When you step through the code with the debugger, what doesn't meet expectations?

Comment: Key that i mention is to inserting the value in textarea..when i debug my code, it will reject the inserting value that have 0..i plan to reject the inserting value that have ALL 0.. u can see the image that i provide..

Answer (score 0):

I'd have written it like:

```
        Dim copiedContent As String = Request.Form(txtCopied.UniqueID)
        For Each row As String In copiedContent.Split(ControlChars.Lf)

            Dim bits = row.Split(ControlChars.Tab)

            If bits.All(Function(x) x = "0") Then Continue For

            dtResult.Rows.Add(bits)

        Next
```

Comment: Thanks Jard, how if i want to add only check all is numerical?

Comment: You mean only add if all are some kind of number? Maybe `If bits.All(Function(x) Double.TryParse(x,0)) Then Continue For`

Comment: Hi Jard i use ur method and its works, thanks!